# Wifi issues with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo laptop, and I'm having lots of issues with my wifi.
Originally, I installed Wicd, that made the connection better, but caused issues by making my wpa_supplicant fail. Now I'm back on network manager, and when I boot up, I instantaneously get good internet speeds, but then it's almost like my wifi "locks up" and my speeds drop to below 1mbps.

Here is my info:

```
# hwinfo --wlan  --short
network:                                                        
  wlp9s0               Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN


# uname -a
Linux cornel-ThinkPad-E520 4.15.0-91-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 28 11:09:48 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

→ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
04:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 07)
09:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]

→ sudo iwconfig wlp9s0 | grep Quality
      Link Quality=57/70  Signal level=-53 dBm  

→ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:72:7e:6d:f9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f0:de:f1:6b:92:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1918  bytes 170637 (170.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1918  bytes 170637 (170.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp9s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.8.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.8.255
        inet6 fe80::bd97:1f4b:4f54:caa1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8c:a9:82:be:fe:6a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26594  bytes 24943171 (24.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24914  bytes 11128513 (11.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I don't know what to do to fix the wifi, but it's really getting me down as I've been struggling for a while.

Comment: Try to upgrade kernel by installing `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately it did not work. Is there another suggestion you may have? My connection works fine when LAN cable is connected to the router, so must be the wifi driver

Comment: For this controller `11n_disable=1` iwlwifi option may help. But there may non-ubuntu reasons that you are not getting good speeds.

Comment: That increased my wifi speed to about 1.6 mbps. Could you point me in the right direction to find what non-ubuntu reasons there may be? The speeds are fine on my Windows laptop and phone (40 mbps)